# Troubles with Zoom on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: zoom-meeting

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, and I installed Zoom client with `sudo apt install zoom-client`. Ever since, I've been having troubles with zoom every once in a while. Meetings will sometimes not load, or take forever to load. I'm not sure what's going on. Is anyone else having a similar problem, or does anyone know how to help?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is coming as you are using older version of zoom.
Now let me tell you how to make this problem alright. Download latest zoom client from [this website](https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_amd64.deb). Then open the folder/directory that has this zoom file and then follow and of the two steps:

**NOTE -** type `sudo apt remove zoom-client` in terminal to remove the old Zoom from your PC before installing the new one.

1. Easy way

   Double left click the downloaded file and install from Ubuntu Software
2. Difficult way

   Open terminal in the directory of `zoom_amd64.deb`. Then type `sudo dpkg -i zoom_amd64.deb`

   Then you will encounter an error; fix it by typing `sudo apt install --fix-broken`.

   Then after the process finishes, type `sudo dpkg -i zoom_amd64.deb` and you will successfully installed Zoom on your system. Now open Zoom and see if you have any problem now.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with **apt** installations of zoom

After months of not being able to launch a meeting or sign into my zoom account using SSO, I finally fixed my issues by installing zoom via **snap**. Here is what I did

```
sudo apt remove zoom
sudo apt purge zoom
sudo snap install zoom-client
```

I am now able to sign in with SSO and launch meetings.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that Zoom works with success using the browser web client instead. It works with both cam and audio. You may use that instead of the Zoom installed client and even save some disk space. I use Firefox under 20.04.1 with no problems. Using the web client removes these install and update issues from the end user. You always have the latest working version.